# My Linearlayout is reverse in some devices Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, reverse

i got a LinearLayout and in some devices all the Views are reverse.

Look Like:
The Good Version: 
[b1] [b2] [b3]

in some devices: 
[b3][b2][b1]

why thats happen ?
how can i Fix that?
Why thats happen only in some devices

code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.gruchka.guesstheemojihebrew.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp" 
    android:background="#801866"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape5"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="מטבעות"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape4"
        android:gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
           android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="שלב"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ce27b2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sun" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/glasses" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:onClick="onClickToHelp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="מטבעות"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10-"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="רמז"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:background="#801866"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:background="#360a2b"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearchangewhenwin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="7"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="6"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="5"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer4"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="4"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer5"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="3"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer6"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer7"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer8"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer9"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="15"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer10"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="14"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer11"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="13"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer12"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="12"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer13"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="11"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer14"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="10"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer15"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="9"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer16"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickAnswer"
            android:tag="8"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearchangewhenwin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ח"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="7"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ז"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="6"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ר"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="5"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter4"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ה"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="4"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter5"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ש"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="3"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter6"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ג"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter7"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ב"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter8"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ת"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter9"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ע"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="15"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter10"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ס"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="14"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter11"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ק"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="13"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter12"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="מ"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="12"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter13"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="ל"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="11"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter14"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="כ"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="10"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter15"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="י"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="9"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/letter16"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="צ"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="onClickLetter"
            android:tag="8"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ididid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="מצויין! תשובה נכונה"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#40e420"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="+10 מטבעות"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#F6DF19" />
             </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-194845939/2483616"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

tnx

Comment: Have you checked: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-native-rtl

Comment: You have many `android:id` repeated, only in the first block you have two `android:id="@+id/textView1"` on the second block one `android:id="@+id/textView5"` followed by another one with the same id. Put a unique id for each view in the same layout.

Comment: Do not ask the same question multiple times.  If you want to add details, edit your original question.

Comment: The problem was that in 4.2 there is RTL Support so i just change the Target to API 9.